# Not getting all organizational units from Active directory

Tags: c#, active-directory

In my Active directory, there are 16 Organizational units under one Organizational unit. I have C# code to get all list of Organizational units.
code line: `subOUsearcher.Filter = "(objectClass=organizationalUnit)";`
But I am getting only 14 OUs out of 16. I also checked properties of that 2 OUs but it is same of other 14 OUs.
Is there any problem with coding or in Active directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`subOUsearcher` is the object of `DirectorySearcher`. This will provide 1000 records and I have more than 1000 records that's why some of OUs are not coming. I just added page size and size limit for that object.

```
subOUsearcher.SizeLimit = Int16.MaxValue;
subOUsearcher.PageSize = Int16.MaxValue;
```

Now all OUs are coming.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the other two are OUs? Or are they Containers?

For example, the built-in Users container is a Container, not an OU. (the `objectClass` is "container", not "organizationalUnit")

AD Users and Computers shows a different icon for each, but check the attributes on them to be sure.

Or are there any permissions preventing your script from seeing them?

Comment: Thank you for help.Yes, that both are OUs, not Container. I checked objectClass for both and it is top: organizationalUnit. I also tried deleting and adding it again but no use.

Comment: Permissions then?

Comment: Yes, I checked Security tab under properties all are same of other OUs.